# SKAction is not running after another action

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction, sknode

I'm basically trying to code a "find the ball under the cups" game for practice.
So there is 3 cups, and one target to find. All using `SKSpriteNode`. The target is randomly a child of one cup, and follows rotations as the parent rotate around an `SKNode`.

Between each game, the program is supposed to show where is the target, by simply animate it up, then down. Here the sequence code :

```
    //THE ANIMATIONS
    SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:100 duration:1];
    SKAction *moveDown = [SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:-100 duration:1];
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.5];
    _presentTargetSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp,wait,moveDown]];
```

And the method using it :

```
- (void) presentTarget
{
    NSLog(@"presentTarget()");
    [_target runAction:_presentTargetSequence completion:^{
        _canMove = YES;
    }];
}
```

The code works fine, but only the first time, after that, the method is called but never go through `[_target runAction ...]`.

BUT it's working if the target does get in the rotation/swap.
So my question is : is there anything that can make a node ignore it run action method ? `NSLog(@"presentTarget()")` is called as I said, but not reaction.

Comment: How do you switch _target? Is it perhaps nil whenever the actions don't run? Set a breakpoint, debug.

Comment: _target is a property of the class runing the game, it is never nil after initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

I find that every time I'm confused about an action not running, it's because the object running the action is not currently in the node hierarchy for the scene. There is no error for this, it just doesn't run the action. So double check to make sure that the object is added to the current scene at the time you ask it to run the action.